# Grails: Integration testing the Mail Plugin

Tags: email, grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to integration test a class that uses the Mail Plugin.  When I run my test (grails test-app -integration EmailerIntegration) I get the error:

**Could not locate mail body layouts/_email. Is it in a plugin? If so you must pass the plugin name in the [plugin] variable**

Is there some initialization code I'm missing from the setUp method of my test case?

Here is the code for the test case:

```
package company

import grails.test.*

class EmailerIntegrationTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testSomething() {
        User owner = new User()
        owner.displayName = "Bob"
        owner.email = "bob@yahoo.com"

        Emailer emailer = new Emailer()
        emailer.sendReadyEmail(owner)
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the class being tested:

```
package company

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

class Emailer {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    ApplicationContext ctx = (ApplicationContext)ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext();
    def mailService = ctx.getBean("mailService");

    def sendReadyEmail = { owner ->
            mailService.sendMail {
                    to owner.email
                    subject "Ready to go"
                    body( view:"layouts/_email", model:[ownerInstance:owner])
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Everett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the plugin author's own tests for the mail plugin at https://github.com/gpc/grails-mail/blob/master/test/integration/org/grails/mail/MailServiceTests.groovy I realized that the paths in the values for the view parameter all begin with a '/'.  I changed my method to

```
def sendReadyEmail = { owner ->
        mailService.sendMail {
                to owner.email
                subject "Ready to go"
                body( view:"/layouts/_email", model:[ownerInstance:owner])
        }
```

And now it works in integration tests and normal program execution.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` parameter in the `sendMail(..)` method is a map with the keys `view`, `model`, and `plugin`. A value for `plugin` is required, and points to *some* other, supporting, plugin, for instance, the name "email-confirmation" for that corresponding plugin.

Your error message is thrown in `org.grails.mail.MailMessageBuilder.renderMailView(Object, Object, Object)`. You can find this class in your Grails project's *plugin* folder.

Unfortunately, I haven't found too much documentation on the Mail plugin. Thus, at the moment, I cannot easily tell about how to use the aforementioned supporting plugins. If you can't get forward, however, I might try to further investigate. Thanks

Comment: No luck.  I wasn't able to find a value to give to the plugin key that made the test work.

Comment: As mentioned, one possible key is "email-confirmation". - Did you, in the meantime, find any relevant documentation on that, or do you have any other findings? - There's no such one-sided thing as "please solve that for me". - I'd be interested in investigating further if you'd make efforts, but I'm not doing others' homework. - We both could also come to the conclusion that there's too few documentation, preventing us from using these plugins. - Thanks

Comment: I should have been more specific, I tried a number of values for the plugin key such as "email-confirmation", "email" and "spring-events" (another plugin I happen to be using).  Every try met with an exception.  However, after finding some extra time to look deeper into this I found an answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting feedback and the solution, and sorry that I couldn't help. - And congratulations! - The non-documentation of most Grails plugins is really absurd. That's "programming by trial and error" and "by reverse engineering" ...